# Jenkins - Populate choice parameter with options from a list variable in a different groovy file

Tags: jenkins, groovy

How can I declare a choice parameter for a declarative pipeline, the choices for which are read from a list in another groovy file?

`l.groovy`

```
opts = ['a','b','c','d']
```

`main.groovy`

```
pipeline {
    parameters {
        choice (
            name: 'CHOICE_LIST',
            choices: config.opts.keySet() as String[],
            description: 'Make a choice'
        )
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hoi,

just join your list with `.join('\n')` should do the trick.

```
choice (
            name: 'CHOICE_LIST',
            choices: config.opts.keySet().join('\n'),
            description: 'Make a choice'
        )
```

Why ?

> ChoiceParameterDefinition requires a delimited string.
>
> https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26143

**UPDATE**

> It's the problem of importing the config that isn't working. How should I import from another groovy file? That's the bigger issue. **cyberbeast**

Add the other groovy.file as a shared library to the pipeline under the job-configuration. 
Create a reference to the pipeline in your job. In my example the Groovy-file is called Prebuild which contains a funtion `getBranchNames()` where I get all branches from a svn-repro.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  libraries {
    lib('PreBuild')
  }
  stages {
    stage('Set Parameters') {
      steps {
        timeout(time: 30, unit: 'SECONDS') {
          script {
            def INPUT_PARAMS = input message: 'Please Provide Parameters', ok: 'Next', parameters: [choice(name: 'Branch_Choice', choices: PreBuild.getBranchNames(), description: 'Which Branch?')]
          }

        }
...
```

The corrospending Prebuild.groovy file looks like this:

```
import groovy.util.XmlSlurper
def getBranchNames(){
    def svn = bat(returnStdout: true, script: 'svn ls https://svn-repro --xml --username John --password Doe --non-interactive --trust-server-cert').trim()
    def result = svn.readLines().drop(1).join(" ")
    def slurper = new XmlSlurper()
    def xml = slurper.parseText(result)
    def name = new ArrayList()
    name.addAll(xml.'*'.'*'.'name')
    return name.join('\n')   
}
```

I parse the svn-command output into an arraylist and return it as a joined string back to my pipeline job.

Be aware that your other Groovy-file has to be in a SCM too. The Library repro needs a special folder structure, find more information here:https://devopscube.com/jenkins-shared-library-tutorial/

Comment: It's the problem of importing the `config` that isn't working. How should I import from another groovy file? That's the bigger issue.

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration. That was pretty comprehensive.